# Interpreter vs. Virtual Machine

Tags: design-patterns, interpreter, vm-implementation

What is the exact difference between Interpreter and Virtual Machine in OOP Design Patterns, especially in the context of game programming?

http://www.oodesign.com/interpreter-pattern.html identifies the interpreter pattern as some kind of *mapping*:

> Map a domain to a language, the language to a grammar, and the grammar to a hierarchical object-oriented design

On the other hand Virtual Machine is supposed to be ... what exactly ?

I assume this must be some kind of collection of objects to do Turing-complete computations. What are its uses besides getting a least common denominator for hardware interoperability (the greatest example being the Java Platform)?

Could you imagine a use case for VM without the purpose of porting an application to another platform (and for games)? Does VM assumes there is explicit abstract language and Interpreter commanding it?

Answer (score 0):

Two different abstractions
So in .Net terms, two different source languages can interpret to the same result, with the added bonus of only having to interpret once.

VM as you say abstracts you from the "physical" environment and as a bonus allows you to specifically optimise for them.

One use for both would be a game engine. Say a basic text adventure.

So you could describe a room in French and english, both would result in the same object and events.

With VM you could action that description in say Winforms or ActionScript

Answer (score 0):

A VM of sorts exists in most languages in the form of a runtime library; and it exists *in potentio* in any interpreter if the parser/compiler portion is removed. But it doesn't really become a real virtual machine until it's properly specified, usually in the form of a grammar for the byte-code.

If you read about Perl internals for version 4, and then something about Parrot or JVM byte-code, the difference should be apparent. The interface between the runtime-support and language/compiler is much more clearly delimited. The virtual machine is a software *engine* which can be optimized with engineering tools.

On a higher level of design, the presence of a virtual machine in a language implementation enables a clearer specification of the permissible semantics of the language. Enforcing bounds-checking on arrays at the very least. :)